# C# read px from BufferedGraphics?

Tags: c#, graphics, buffer

I currently use the BufferGraphics object if I want to animate my Graphics in C#. The thing is, I would like to know how to access the data which I stored.

I use the buffer to do things like:

```
    bufferContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
    bufferGraphics= bufferContext.Allocate(g, this.DisplayRectangle);

     // In some function it would then draw some rectangles or paths etcetera and call
     // bufferGraphics.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);

    bufferGraphics.Render(g);
    bufferGraphics.Dispose();
```

**Question:** But how can I loop through the pixels that I store in BufferGraphics?

**Note**: I am not allowed to show any source code, however my question should be clear to you if you ever used the bufferGraphics object.

Comment: So you want to access the pixels without rendering them?

Comment: @TaW yes just that. Just the raw pixel information so that I can parse the infos later (color etc). I expect some sort of unsigned 32 bit integers (I guess that is how they are stored?). Not quite sure really in what form the graphics are saved inside the buffer but I really need to be able to iterate through the pixels

Comment: Good question, ive been wondering how this works myself.

Comment: @TaW Is it even possible?

Comment: I consider making BufferedGraphics *public* a design-mistake.  It has a name that is entirely too attractive but almost never gets used correctly.  It does not here, constantly allocating and destroying the object is *very* inefficient.  The quest is a quixotic one at that, it gets its speed by using a DDB (Device Dependent Bitmap).  Which means that you can't rely on its pixel format.  At least they did not make the mistake of making it easy to get to the raw buffer storage.  Use a Bitmap, choose its pixel format very carefully.  Using the wrong one makes your animation code ~10 times slower.

Comment: @HansPassant you are very right. So I can make a bitmap from my graphic? I do need the buffer though right? I mean otherwise I have flickering.I cant image without it. I can however store the objects outside the function then I just reuse the buffer. I do have to render and dispose though. (I think)

Comment: Looking at the [sources](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/BufferedGraphicsContext@cs/1/BufferedGraphicsContext@cs) I doubt that it is possible and also that it would make much sense, unless you would eventually render to a display with less than 32bpp.. - The way I read the purpose, you should not hope to gain speed but the option to have quite differerent buffering schemes for different postion of your application..

Comment: @TaW need to do some pixel collision detection by comparing px A with px B. Thats why. Hans Passant made a point though, I could create a bitmap.

Comment: Yes, that is the way to go. For collision detection the format may or may not matter; for pushing it to the screen [PARGB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534412%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is highly [recommended](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/66909/rendering-fast-with-gdi-what-to-do-and-what-not-to)